# How to fetch list of transactions using hyperledger fabric node sdk

Tags: node.js, transactions, sdk, fetch, hyperledger-fabric

I want to fetch list of transaction using the node sdk, but I couldn't find any reference for that, I'm using high level node sdk of the fabric.

Below is my code that I have used to connect to the network:

```js
'use strict';

const { FileSystemWallet, Gateway } = require('fabric-network');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const ccpPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'connection.json');
const ccpJSON = fs.readFileSync(ccpPath, 'utf8');
const ccp = JSON.parse(ccpJSON);

async function main() {
    const identity = 'testuser';

    try {

        // Create a new file system based wallet for managing identities.
        const walletPath = path.join(process.cwd(), 'wallet');
        const wallet = new FileSystemWallet(walletPath);
        console.log(`Wallet path: ${walletPath}`);

        // Check to see if we've already enrolled the user.
        const userExists = await wallet.exists(identity);
        if (!userExists) {
            console.log(`An identity for the user "${identity}" does not exist in the wallet`);
            console.log('Run the registerUser.js application before retrying');
            return;
        }

        // Create a new gateway for connecting to our peer node.
        const gateway = new Gateway();
        await gateway.connect(ccp, { wallet, identity: identity, discovery: { enabled: false } });

        // Get the network (channel) our contract is deployed to.
        const network = await gateway.getNetwork('mychannel');


    } catch (error) {
        console.error(`Error: ${error}`);
        process.exit(1);
    }
}

main();
```

I'm connected to the network, but don't what function to use to fetch recent transactions and paginate.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

see https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/release-1.4/Channel.html#queryBlock - and the block info (with the tx_ids inside the data array) is described here -> https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/release-1.4/global.html#Block

Comment: Isn't there a simple function or call that gives me transactions in one go in chronological order?

Comment: the process is to get the recent block no first and traverse through the blocks and extract the transaction ids and then fetch single transaction with that id, right? Correct me If I'm wrong. If yes, then It's a lot of calls and time to get the transactions, is there a better way to do this?